# htaccess forbidden only at www.example.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services

I want access to both www and non-www versions of my URL. Unfortunately, just adding a record for this isn't working.

Using AWS Route 53, I have a hosted zone at mydomain.com. Inside of it, I have my nameservers as well as a record pointing to the EC2 instance. This works great, but only for mydomain.com. As soon as you type in www.example.com, you get "Forbidden". Using https://www.example.com works. The tricky thing here is that if you access http://example.com, you get the "Forbidden" error, and can't use the site.

Is there something I should change Route 53 side? Or is it a .htaccess thing? If it is, what do I add?

---

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`
```

Comment: Can you post you DNS config and your htaccess file?

Comment: added .htaccess, although I'm unsure how to add DNS config from route 53.

Comment: Route53 does not know anything or care about protocols (e.g. http / https). This will be a web server configuration issue.

Comment: So http://example.com and www.example.com gives you Forbidden error. It means the site is not accessible over HTTP protocol.

send domain's error log in order to identify why http does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Apache settings

I would use an Apache [virtual host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/index.html) and set the `www` address as a `ServerAlias`.

Something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

If you're using SSL/TLS (which you should be), your Virtual Hosts file would look something like this (if using [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/))

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com example.com
    Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    <Directory /var/www/example.com>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/chain.pem
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in AWS using bitnami LAMP instance and LetsEncrypt certificate.

after checking "apachectl -S", I found that there are two definitions for the same virtual host, one from /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf and the second one from  /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf.

Then I remembered that I tried to renew my certificates with bitnami /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool which stopped with an error, Then I used certbot renew.

So by trying two renewing methods of certificate I ended up with a mess in the apache configuration of virtual hosts.

Finally, by removing virtual host part from /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf my problem was solved.